# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTransaction' of null" error when deploying to Ropsten testnet using hardhat

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-721, ropsten, hardhat-deploy

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendTransaction' of null
> at ContractFactory. (/Users/UserName/Downloads/nft-marketplace-ethereum/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:1237:38)
> at step (/Users/UserName/Downloads/nft-marketplace-ethereum/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
> at Object.next (/Users/UserName/Downloads/nft-marketplace-ethereum/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
> at fulfilled (/Users/UserName/Downloads/nft-marketplace-ethereum/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)

when running the command:

> npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten

my deploy.js file is

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const NFTmarket = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTmarket");
  const nftmarket = await NFTmarket.deploy();

  await nftmarket.deployed();

  console.log("nftmarket deployed to:", nftmarket.address);

  const NFTtoken = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTtoken");
  const nfttoken = await NFTtoken.deploy(nftmarket.address);
  await nfttoken.deployed();
  console.log("nfttoken deployed to:", nfttoken.address); 
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

my index.js file is

```
export default function Home() {

  const router = useRouter();
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([]);
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState("not-loaded");

  useEffect(() => {
    loadNFTs();
  }, []);
  async function loadNFTs() {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/{project_id}");
    const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(
      nftaddress,
      NFTtoken.abi,
      provider
    );
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(
      nftmarketaddress,
      NFTmarket.abi,
      provider
    );
    const data = await marketContract.unsoldNFTs();

    const items = await Promise.all(
      data.map(async (i) => {
        const tokenUri = await tokenContract.tokenURI(i.tokenid);
        const meta = await axios.get(tokenUri);
        let price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(
          i.selling_price.toString(),
          "ether"
        );
        let item = {
          price,
          tokenid: i.tokenid.toNumber(),
          seller: i.seller,
          owner: i.owner,
          image: meta.data.image,
          name: meta.data.name,
          description: meta.data.description,
        };
        return item;
      })
    );
    setNfts(items);
    setLoadingState("loaded");
  }
  async function buyNft(nft) {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      nftmarketaddress,
      NFTmarket.abi,
      signer
    );
    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), "ether");
    const transaction = await contract.Sale(nftaddress, nft.tokenid, {
      value: price,
    });
    await transaction.wait();
    loadNFTs();
  }
```

my hardhat.config.js is

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
const fs = require('fs');
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("privatekey").toString()
// const infuraId = fs.readFileSync(".infuraid").toString().trim() || "";


module.exports = {
  networks:{
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337
    },
    ropsten: {
      url: "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/{project_id}",
      account: [privateKey]
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{project_id}",
      account: [privateKey]
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.4",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error when my private key wasn't properly populated.

I also would use an environment variable like `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY`, so it's not hard-coded into your hardhat config.

Answer (score 1):

In your hardhat.config.js

```
mainnet: {
  url: "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{project_id}",
  account: [privateKey]
}
```

should be accounts instead of account. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I was using multiple signers:

```js
const [deployer, account, ...] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

for testing on localhost, but I only added `1` private key when deploying to the testnet.